# How to add camera module pipeline with A-Frame

Tags: 8thwall-xr

I am new to 8th wall, and frontend development. I'm developing a project with a bunch of image-target experiences developed in a-frame. And on top of that I need to scan QR code in the AR.
From what I see in the documentation, I can add camera pipeline module. But my question is that how can I start implementing that with a-frame component register? the start code is here.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('qr-scan', {
  schema: {
  },
  init: function () {
    // Install a module which gets the camera feed as a UInt8Array.
    XR8.addCameraPipelineModule(
    XR8.CameraPixelArray.pipelineModule({luminance: true, width: 240, height: 320}))
    // Install a module that draws the camera feed to the canvas.
    XR8.addCameraPipelineModule(XR8.GlTextureRenderer.pipelineModule())
    // Create our custom application logic for scanning and displaying QR codes.
    XR8.addCameraPipelineModule({
      name : 'qrscan',
      onProcessCpu : ({onProcessGpuResult}) => {
        // CameraPixelArray.pipelineModule() returned these in onProcessGpu.
        const { pixels, rows, cols, rowBytes } = onProcesGpuResult.camerapixelarray
        const { wasFound, url, corners } = findQrCode(pixels, rows, cols, rowBytes)
        return { wasFound, url, corners }
      },
      onUpdate : ({onProcessCpuResult}) => {
        // These were returned by this module ('qrscan') in onProcessCpu
        const {wasFound, url, corners } = onProcessCpuResult.qrscan
        if (wasFound) {
          showUrlAndCorners(url, corners)
        }
      },
    })
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

8th Wall provides an example of combining the `XR8.addCameraPipelineModule` workflow with A-Frame. You create an A-Frame component and then attach it to your `<a-scene>` element. In the example, they use event listeners to control the order in which elements are loaded. However, it should technically be possible to add the camera pipeline as an A-Frame component like in your original code.

```js
const xrScene = `
<a-scene xrweb xrextras-tap-recenter xrextras-almost-there xrextras-loading xrextras-runtime-error
    xrextras-gesture-detector throw-error>
  <a-camera position="0 3 3"></a-camera>
  <a-box position="0 0.5 -1" material="color: #7611B6;" shadow xrextras-one-finger-rotate></a-box>
  <a-box scale="100 2 100" position="0 -1 0" material="shader: shadow" shadow></a-box>
</a-scene>
`
const throwErrorComponent = {
    init: function() {
        // A pipeline module that throws an error after 300 frames -- illustrates the error
        // handinling in xrweb-runtime-error.
        const throwerrorPipelineModule = () => {
            let frame = 0
            return {
                name: 'throwerror',
                onUpdate: () => {
                    if (++frame > 300) {
                        throw Error('Too many frames!')
                    }
                },
            }
        }
        const load = () => {
            XR.addCameraPipelineModule(throwerrorPipelineModule())
        }
        window.XRExtras && window.XR ? load() : window.addEventListener('xrandextrasloaded', load)
    }
}
window.XRExtras.AFrame.loadAFrameForXr({
        version: 'latest',
        components: {
            'throw-error': throwErrorComponent
        }
    })
    .then(() => document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', xrScene))
```

Source: https://github.com/8thwall/web/blob/0dc4b50018e8398e989d1724748646ea8145482f/xrextras/index-aframe.html#L16-L40

Answer (score 0):

What you need to be doing, like you have done already, is to add a pipeline to XR8 via `addCameraPipelineModules`. There is honestly nothing more than that. Here is code that you can use if you try to combine the [Flyer](https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/flyer-aframe) demo, and the [QR Code camera pipeline](https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/camera-qrcode) demo.

```
<!-- === body.html === -->
<div style="z-index: 10" id="url"></div>    

// === app.js === 
import {qrprocessPipelineModule, qrdisplayPipelineModule} from './qr'

const onxrloaded = () => {

  const load = () => {
    XR8.addCameraPipelineModules([
        // Provides pixels.
      XR8.CameraPixelArray.pipelineModule({luminance: true, maxDimension: 640}),
        // Custom provided pipelines
      qrprocessPipelineModule(),
      qrdisplayPipelineModule(document.getElementById('url')),
    ])
  }

  // Wait until <a-frame> has loaded
  const pipelineEventListener = window.addEventListener('xrandextrasloaded', () => {
    load()
    window.removeEventListener('xrandextrasloaded', pipelineEventListener)
  })
}

onxrloaded()
```

Down below is slimmed down code from the [QR Code example](https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/camera-qrcode), where `qrprocessPipelineModule` process image data from the camera followed by `qrdisplayPipelineModule` to update `div#url`.

```
// === qr.js ===

// Code from https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode
import {qrcode} from './jsqrcode/src/qrcode'

// Define a custom pipeline module. This module scans the camera feed for qr codes, and makes the
// result available to other modules in onUpdate. It requires that the CameraPixelArray module is
// installed and configured to provide a luminance (black and white) image.
const qrprocessPipelineModule = () => ({
  name: 'qrprocess',
  onProcessCpu: ({processGpuResult}) => {
    // Check whether there is any data ready to process.
    if (!processGpuResult.camerapixelarray || !processGpuResult.camerapixelarray.pixels) {
      return {found: false}
    }

    try {
      // Set input variables on the global qrcode object before calling qrcode.process().
      const {rows, cols} = processGpuResult.camerapixelarray
      qrcode.width = cols
      qrcode.height = rows
      qrcode.grayscale = () => processGpuResult.camerapixelarray.pixels

      // returns {processGpuResult, processCpuResult}
      return qrcode.process()
    } catch (e) {
      return {found: false}  // jsqrcode throws errors when qr codes are not found in an image.
    }
  },
})

// Define a custom pipeline module. This module updates UI elements with the result of the QR code
// scanning, and navigates to the found url on any tap to the screen.
const qrdisplayPipelineModule = (url) => {
  let lastSeen = 0
  let canvas_

  return {
    name: 'qrdisplay',
    onStart: ({canvas}) => {
      url.style.visibility = 'visible'  // Show the card that displays the url.
      canvas_ = canvas
    },
    onUpdate: ({processGpuResult, processCpuResult}) => {
      if (!processCpuResult.qrprocess) {
        return
      }

      const {found, foundText, points} = processCpuResult.qrprocess

      // Toggle display text based on whether a qrcode result was found.
      if (found) {
        url.innerHTML = `<u>${foundText}</u>`
        url.href = foundText
        lastSeen = Date.now()
      } else if (Date.now() - lastSeen > 5000) {
        url.innerHTML = 'Scanning for QR Code...'
        url.href = ''
      }
    },
  }
}

export {qrprocessPipelineModule, qrdisplayPipelineModule}
```